# Usage of HSM in Corda

Tags: corda, hsm

must all nodes in a given corda network use the same HSM providers? Or is it possible that certain nodes use provider A, some of them use provider B, and the others opt to store their private keys in their local node? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

HSM support for node's private keys is on the node base. As long as it is supoorted by Corda's HSM list, it will be ok.

Find more information about HSM support at https://docs.corda.r3.com/cryptoservice-configuration.html

First time learning about Corda? Join the Corda community at slack.corda.net!